# Cannot build Mercurial from sources in CentOS

Tags: linux, build, mercurial, centos, rpm

I'm trying to build Mercurial on CentOS 6, so here is what I've done so far:

I got mercurial's latest sources, file is named `mercurial-2.4.1.tar.gz`

I try running rpmbuild on it and I get the following:

```
# rpmbuild -tb mercurial-2.4.1.tar.gz
error: File /home/someuser/rpms/mercurial/mercurial-snapshot.tar.gz: No such file or directory
```

So I try creating the file that it wants by copying from the other guy:

```
# cp mercurial-2.4.1.tar.gz mercurial-snapshot.tar.gz
```

I try again, appears to pass the previous error:

```
# rpmbuild -tb mercurial-2.4.1.tar.gz
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.vV9ZXc
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ rm -rf mercurial-snapshot
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /home/someuser/rpms/mercurial/mercurial-snapshot.tar.gz
+ /bin/tar -xf -
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ cd mercurial-snapshot
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.vV9ZXc: line 34: cd: mercurial-snapshot: No such file or directory
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.vV9ZXc (%prep)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.vV9ZXc (%prep)
```

I'm not sure what is happening, my guess is that rpmbuild is not being able to create files... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I have found to build an RPM for CentOS that isn't already available is to find a source RPM from Fedora and do `rpmbuild --rebuild` on it. CentOS [documents it here](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM) but seems to be down right now.

[Here](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/fedora/devel/rawhide/src/m/mercurial-2.4.1-1.fc19.src.html) is a src RPM you can give a try to start with.

Comment: This is a possible solution, but I want to do this the "right" way (BTW, I already installed the latest Mercurial by finding the actual CentOS package, but I want to build from source for next time I update)

Comment: OK, then it looks like you should try replacing the word "snapshot" in the specfile you found with the version number you are trying to build. Or even better set a macro. Can you post the specfile you are trying to use (it's in the tar file).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a /var/tmp/ directory or can't write to it. Try creating it: `mkdir /var/tmp` - you may have to use "sudo" for this to work, depending on the setup of your system.

Answer (score 0):

I think that creating tarball by cp command is not good.

You should rename the mercurial-[version]/ directory generated after extracting the official tarball to mercuial-snapshot/ and then create zipped tar archive of the directory named mercurial-snapshot.tar.gz.

```
$ tar zxvf mercurial-2.4.1.tar.gz 
$ mv mercurial-2.4.1 mercurial-snapshot
$ tar zcvf mercurial-snapshot.tar.gz mercurial-snapshot
```

Comment: The tarball was already created, not sure why I would have to untar, then create the tar all over again

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the bundled spec file has a version default of "snapshot", so it's going to look for a tar file named "mercurial-snapshot.tar.gz", and also expects the extracted directory to be "mercurial-snapshot" (so you can't just rename the tar file).

The best way (or at least, **a** way) to handle this is to extract the spec file, update it with the correct version and release number, then build the rpm from that.

Here's the process:

```
tar fxz mercurial-X.Y.tar.gz --strip-components=2 mercurial-X.Y/contrib/mercurial.spec
```

Place the spec file in rpmbuild/SPECS and edit it.  Replace the "Version: snapshot" line with "Version: X.Y", and replace the "Release: 0" line with "Release: 1.xyz" where xyz is a custom tag so you know that you built the package yourself.

Then run rpmbuild:

```
rpmbuild -bb --target=i686 SPECS/mercurial.spec
```

Use --target=x86_64 if you're on and building for a 64-bit system.

You should then have a correctly built and named rpm file in the RPMS/$target directory.